# Hi,Both Client generation, token generation is taking around 3 seconds. is this expected? or can i overcome it? in Android for RecaptchaEnterprise

Tags: android, recaptcha-enterprise

Responses are taking more time around 3 seconds for both client, token generation in Android device.

tried using java code for Android, but responses are taking more time. Expecting client, token generation in less than or around 1 second.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.